# Compact camera for hiking and city tourists

Tags: camera

I have a Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ41. You can see [images I took](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma) online, but to summarize:

I want to take / took images of

- [Animals](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma/Animals): Super hard at the moment, many of my images are blurry.
- [Landscapes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma/Landscapes)
- [Plants](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma/Plants)
- [Food](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma/Food)
- [City Tourism](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images_by_Martin_Thoma/Barcelona)

### What is important to me

- **Sharp images**: Especially for animal images, I had to throw away a lot.
- **Size**: Not too bulky - it should fit in the side bag of my Deuter Air Contact 55+10
  (like the Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ40); I don't care about weight
- **Colors**: Some of my landscape images grayish
- **Grip**: I want to be able to make selfies with it
- **On/off**: Similar to the grip one - I don't want to accidentially turn it on / off.
- **Price** should at maximum be 700 EUR. Rather something like 500 EUR, but more
  than 300 EUR is fine.
- **Battery life**: I want to be able to have the camera with me for a day with one
  battery. So I guess something like 150 shots should easily be possible.

Optional:

- GPS: I like when my images are geo-tagged.
- Panorama: Either it should be very good or I don't need it. The Panorama function of the TZ41 is not worth it. I have a smartphone (Samsung S7) as well.

### What is not important

- Touch screen
- NFC
- Video

### Candidates

From my initial research, I have the impression the following cameras could fit my need:

- Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ100
- Sony Cyber-shot RX100 IV
- Sony Cyber-shot RX100 III
- G7 X Mark II

Please note that I don't want to exclude other cameras; it's just what I found so far.

I am, however, not sure which one would be best and if the improvement is that much compared to my current Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ41. What did change to the TZ100? What should I look for?

Comment: why not a phone

Comment: I don't think the quality is good enough. But I'm not too sure. My S7 actually gives pretty nice photos; I'll try this more often to compare.

Comment: You put compact camera in the title but said weight is basically irrelevant. Would you consider a compact system camera?

Comment: To be fair, the s7 has a sick camera, and the pixel 2 has the highest rated phone camera, so if you were considering a new phone, then that's a phone and camera all in one, unless you need the super zoom that the tz range offers